# How can I get value from Column A if select specific value from Column B in an Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a "Country" array with "Country_ID" and "Country_Name" columns.
How can I get "Country_Name" value if "Country_ID" is 123? Can I get it done in valueForKey?

How can I write this? Example Country ID = 123, Country Name = Japan

```
NSArray *ary = [CountryArray valueForKey:@"Country_Name"];
```

Comment: Write a `for` loop that examines each element of the array in turn and checks to see if it is the country you are looking for. If it is, then get the name and `break` out of the loop

Comment: Beyond for loop, is there any other easier method to do that? I have specific int to pass in order to get Country Name

Comment: It's an array. The only way to search is to iterate over it. If the array is sorted then you could use a binary search, but honestly there are only a couple of hundred countries in the world. A linear search won't take very long. You could build a dictionary, but you would need to wrap the Ints in NSNumber as NSDictionary can't have scalar types as keys, so it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: I guess you could sort the array and pad it with invalid objects where there are discontinuities in your country ids so that the country id was just the index of the country object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate to filter your results like :-

```
NSString *countryID=@"123";
NSString *countryName=@"Japan";
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Country_ID = %@ AND Country_Name = %@",countryID,countryName];
NSArray *filteredArray=[CountryArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to associate a `Country_ID` with a `Country_Name`, you can use a dictionary.

```
NSArray *countryIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"key", @"123", nil];
NSArray *countryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"value", @"Japan", nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: countryNames forKeys: countryIDs];
NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey: @"123"]);//prints out "Japan"
```

Apple has documentation for using dictionaries in Objective-C with examples.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?changes=_4